# Eloquent, how to select rows if a value is present in any of two tables?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have  tables that have the following structure, one product can have many skus:

```
  product          skus
  id               product_id
  sku_prin         sku
  other fields     other fields
```

If a search value is present in either sku_prin of products table or sku of skus table the row should be selected.

```
$search_value = "ramdom_value";

$query = product::query();


$result = $query->with(['skus' => function($q) use($search_value){

//  this code won't work the orWhere cannot change the context of skus table
  $q->where('sku', $search_value)->orWhere('products.sku_prin', $search_value)

}])->paginate(50);
```

Above is my failed attempt. How can accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) function of Eloquent

Consider you have the product and skus model like this

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product';

    public function sku()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Skus', 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```php
class Skus extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'skus';

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

You can obtain your data with Eloquent like this

```php
$keyword = 'some keyword'

Product::where('sku_prin', '=', $keyword)  // for product table
->orWhereHas('sku', function($query) use ($keyword) {
    $query->where('sku', '=', $keyword);  // for sku table
});
```

Or even more, do the fuzzy whereLike query with exploding keywords from a single string

```php
$keywordString = 'keyword1 keyword2';
$keywords = explode(' ', $keywordString);

Product::where(function($query) use ($keywords) { // for product table
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    {
        $query->orWhere('sku_prin', 'like', "%$keyword%");
    }
})  
->orWhereHas('sku', function($query) use ($keywords) { // for sku table
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    {
        $query->orWhere('sku', '=', $keyword);
    }
});
```